# Validating hidden input

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for validating a form.

My problem is that I have an input field of type hidden and I want to make it required, but the form remains valid also when this field is empty.

A lookup field (an input with type text) fills this hidden field when is selected a value. The description of the value is put near the lookup field, and the lookup field remains empty (this is the behavior I want for the lookup).

What I want to do now is to redirect the validation to the lookup field. If the hidden field is empty when pressing submit, to show a message "This field is required" near lookup field.

```
<input type="text" size="20" tabindex="17" id="txtR17799_0_0" name="txtR17799_0_0" selectorviewid="18967" viewpageid="-1" class="requiredInput" onfocus="new AutoSuggestControl(this, 13185, 18967);" matchfield="name" matchrule="ST" suggtype="rObj" ismultiple="false" autocomplete="off">
...
<input type="hidden" id="R17799_0_0" name="R17799_0_0" value="" hidenchange="rbv_glf[0]='R17799'; rbf_showSubjectOnRow(0);" required="" novalidate="novalidate">
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your markup? Also, why are you validating a hidden input and not the "lookup field"?

Comment: The lookup field remains empty after is selected a value (it fills the description - that is near the lookup and also it fills the hidden input field with the ID). So i cannot put the validation on it since is always empty...

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us your markup.